# plotting glm interactions: "newdata=" structure in predict() function

Tags: r, prediction, glm, interaction, predict

My problem is with the `predict()` function, its structure, and plotting the predictions.

Using the predictions coming from my model, I would like to visualize how my significant factors (and their interaction) affect the probability of my response variable.

My model:

```
m1  <-glm ( mating ~  behv * pop + 
                      I(behv^2) * pop + condition, 
                      data=data1, family=binomial(logit))
```

*mating*: individual has mated or not (factor, binomial: 0,1)

*pop*: population (factor, 4 levels)

*behv*: behaviour (numeric, scaled & centered)

*condition*: relative fat content (numeric, scaled & centered)

Significant effects after running the glm:

**pop1**

**condition**

**behv*pop2**

**behv^2*pop1**

Although I have read the help pages, previous answers to similar questions, tutorials etc., I couldn't figure out how to structure the `newdata=` part in the `predict()` function. The effects I want to visualise (given above) might give a clue of what I want: For the "**behv*pop2**" interaction, for  example, I would like to get a graph that shows how the behaviour of individuals from population-2 can influence whether they will mate or not (probability from 0 to 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the only thing that `predict` expects is that the names of the columns in `newdata` exactly match the column names used in the formula. And you must have values for each of your predictors. Here's some sample data.

```
#sample data
set.seed(16)
data <- data.frame(
    mating=sample(0:1, 200, replace=T),
    pop=sample(letters[1:4], 200, replace=T),
    behv = scale(rpois(200,10)),
    condition = scale(rnorm(200,5))
)

data1<-data[1:150,]     #for model fitting
data2<-data[51:200,-1]  #for predicting
```

Then this will fit the model using `data1` and predict into `data2`

```
model<-glm ( mating ~  behv * pop + 
    I(behv^2) * pop + condition, 
    data=data1, 
    family=binomial(logit)) 

predict(model, newdata=data2, type="response")
```

Using `type="response"` will give you the predicted probabilities.

Now to make predictions, you don't have to use a subset from the exact same `data.frame`. You can create a new one to investigate a particular range of values (just make sure the column names match up. So in order to explore `behv*pop2` (or `behv*popb` in my sample data), I might create a data.frame like this

```
popbbehv<-data.frame(
    pop="b",
    behv=seq(from=min(data$behv), to=max(data$behv), length.out=100),
    condition = mean(data$condition)
)
```

Here I fix `pop="b"` so i'm only looking at the `pop`, and since I have to supply `condition` as well, i fix that at the mean of the original data. (I could have just put in 0 since the data is centered and scaled.) Now I specify a range of `behv` values i'm interested in. Here i just took the range of the original data and split it into 100 regions. This will give me enough points to plot. So again i use `predict` to get

```
popbbehvpred<-predict(model, newdata=popbbehv, type="response")
```

and then I can plot that with

```
plot(popbbehvpred~behv, popbbehv, type="l")
```

[image: results plot]

Although nothing is significant in my fake data, we can see that higher behavior values  seem to result in less mating for population B.